# Is it possible to make an on-off loop circuit with common transistors?

Tags: transistors, switches, dc

Can I make a circuit that turns something like LED or similar small DC devices turn on for a second then turn off one second then on and loop like this with transistor only? I mean without using any IC or relay. I have common transistors in hand like 2N2222, BC547, BC557 etc. Timing can vary but is it possible? I can provide different power source for the switching circuit.

Comment: Try to google "transistor oscillator"

Comment: @Aaron I want to keep it on and off for longer like one or few seconds. Found no help on that.

Comment: Generally the easier types of transistor oscillator work by charging and discharging a capacitance.  They can be slowed down by using higher resistance to charge and discharge a larger capacitor.  For ones where your transistors turn hard on and hard off, you can use the capacitor time constant formula to calculate the output frequency.  If you want a nice cheap "better" but still easy way to do this, you might want to get some 555 timers.  They're not the best at anything, but they're cheap and you can learn a lot of basic circuits with them.

Comment: Do you have a variety of resistors and capacitors on hand?  What about a DC power supply, breadboard and voltage regulators?

Comment: @KH Yes I have variety of resistors and capacitors. I don't have DC power supply/voltage regulators. I'm using array of simple 3.7v rechargeable batterie. Actually I could buy 555 timers as I found some schematics online, but I wanted to learn if it's possible with Transistor along with other basic components. As you mentioned, I have variety of resistors and capacitors, want to learn about the formula.

Comment: You'll definitely want to get some voltage regulators, 7805, 7905, 7812, 7912 and some low voltage 1 amp buck and boost converters would help get you started as well.  It's difficult to do anything involving timing well without a steady voltage, but if you google the transistor oscillator circuit aaron mentions, you'll find enough information to slap one together.  Once you've decided on a circuit that looks fairly simple, and you've studied what it's supposed to do, you can come back here and ask questions after you build it if parts of it don't work as you believe they should.